# DocumentListener not calling insertUpdate method

Tags: java, swing, events, documentlistener, focuslistener

I'm adding some custom listeners to my class, but document events are not firing. Why?

```
public class MyClass{
        MyCustomListener mcl = new MyCustomListener();          
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                    getTxt_ppu().add(new CustomTextField(40));
                    getTxt_ppu().get(i).getDocument().addDocumentListener(mcl);
                    getTxt_ppu().get(i).addFocusListener(mcl);
        }
        //...Some code....
        private class MyCustomListener implements DocumentListener, FocusListener, Serializable {
            int index;

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

                 System.out.println("Focus");
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("a");

            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {     
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {    
            }
        }
```

}

When executing and clicking on my `CustomTextField` it does shows in console "Focus", but when I type something inside the textfield "a" is never printed.
When I typing something inside the `insertUpdate` method, eclipse shows a red msg at the bottom that says

> "The method insertUpdate(DocumentEvent) of type MyClass.MyCustomListener must
>   override or implement a supertype method"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, I mean at least I didn't anything wrong with your adding document event listener part. Have a look at the demo compare what you did, you may find the issue:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/DocumentEventDemoProject/src/events/DocumentEventDemo.java

Answer (score 0):

This has no sense.

I had to addDocumentListener again, from the focusGained method..

```
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        Object o = e.getSource();
        if(o instanceof CustomTextField) {  
            ((CustomTextField)o).getDocument().addDocumentListener(mcl);
        }
    }
```